# bash programming STDIN redirect

Tags: bash

I want to get the home directory of a user of a unix system.  Why doesn't the following work:

```
# sudo su $offender -c "bash -s < <(echo echo \$HOME)"
sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Comment: Why doesn't `sudo su $offender -c 'echo $HOME'` work for you?

Comment: I get a "redirection unexpected" error

Comment: Fully expected.  `< <` doesn't make much sense.  What i'm asking is, why all the shell gymnastics?  It'd seem you don't need all the redirection and echoing commands and such...

Comment: Guess we should ask...what OS is this?  Is it one where `sh` isn't a link to `bash`?  (On my RH/CentOS Linux boxes, `sh` is actually `bash`...probably why i'm not seeing the issue you're having.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me in Ubuntu and Fedora using `sudo su $offender -c "echo \$HOME"`

You could also gouge it from your /etc/passwd file like so:

```
grep "^$offender" /etc/passwd | cut -d':' -f6
```

Comment: Sometimes the obvious escapes me. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know why it doesn't work, but here's a way to get the home directory that does not involve spawning a shell as that user:

```
getent passwd "${offender:?No Offending Account Given}" | awk -F':' 'NR==1{print $6}'
```

Comment: Or do `sudo su ${offender} -c 'bash -c "echo $HOME"'`, or `sudo su ${offender} -c "bash -s <<<'echo \$HOME'"` if you insist on running a process as the user you want to get information for.

Answer (score 0):

The direct problem is that `sh` does not recognize process substitution (the `<(echo $HOME)`) notation, even when it is a link to `bash`.

It seems like a rather brute force way to get the information.  Doesn't:

```
eval echo ~$offender
```

work for you?